# Why are kiCAD Net Labels not searchable when converted to pdf?

Tags: schematics, kicad

I converted the kicad schematics to pdf but when I search for "I2C_SENSORS_SCL" - the text does not show up. Is there any way to make the net names searchable text in the pdf?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is a feature in the next version of KiCad (v5).  See https://bugs.launchpad.net/kicad/+bug/1710454 for details.

Quoting from link:

> **jean-pierre charras (jp-charras) wrote on 2017-08-15:**
> Commit 0999b5cb77c9a1b44e7e194071c2acb7e33ffb1d should work in PDF files.
> (search texts are enabled in Eeschema and Pcbnew).

> Please try it (especially with texts using non ASCII8 chars)

If you want to try out the v5 RC, you can download a nightly build from

- https://downloads.kicad.org/kicad/windows/explore/nightlies (Windows)
- https://downloads.kicad.org/kicad/macos/explore/nightlies (Mac)
- [https://launchpad.net/~kicad/+archive/ubuntu/kicad-dev-nightly/](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekicad/+archive/ubuntu/kicad-dev-nightly/) (Ubuntu)

**Warning**: While KiCad 5 is currently (5/14/18) at Release Candidate, not all known bugs are fixed and it is possible that you will experience crashes and/or data loss.  Using Version 5 on your v4 schematics and layouts will require you to convert them to a new, non-backwards-compatible format.  Be sure to back up your data before trying and keep backups during your work.  And remember to [report any bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kicad/+filebug) so they get fixed!